# Create new columns using a column value and fill values from another column

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table in PostgreSQL

```
id  type  name
146 INN Ofloxacin
146 TRADE_NAME  Ocuflox
146 TRADE_NAME  Ofloxacin
146 TRADE_NAME  Tarivid i.v.
146 TRADE_NAME  Tarivid 400
147 TRADE_NAME  Mictral
147 TRADE_NAME  Neggram
543 INN Amphetamine
543 INN Amfetamine
543 TRADE_NAME  Adzenys xr-odt
543 TRADE_NAME  Adzenys er
543 TRADE_NAME  Dyanavel xr
```

I would like to create two new columns trade_name and inn and fill their respective value (copying over or concatenate the INN values) from column 'name'. I am expecting the following output

```
id  trade_name      inn  
146 Ocuflox         Ofloxacin
146 Ofloxacin       Ofloxacin
146 Tarivid i.v.    Ofloxacin
146 Tarivid 400     Ofloxacin
147 Mictral         Ofloxacin
147 Neggram         Ofloxacin
543 Adzenys xr-odt  Amphetamine | Amfetamine
543 Adzenys er      Amphetamine | Amfetamine
543 Dyanavel xr     Amphetamine | Amfetamine
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't create new columns in that table. Create an altogether new table, if you must. But really this output should be created dynamically in a query only, not stored in this denormalised format - create a *view* instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a result set of distinct ids and then join that back to the same table. Once to get trade_names and once to get inn records:

```
SELECT ids.id,
     tradenames.name as trade_name,
     inns.name as inn
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM yourtable) as ids
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable as tradenames 
        ON ids.id = tradenames.id
        AND tradenames.type = 'TRADE_NAME'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable as inns
        ON ids.id = inns.id
        AND inns.type = 'INNS';
```

You might also be able to pull this off with a pivot, but I think that would be overkill for the two output columns you are after.